# Why are there zeros next to each tag under the tab tags?

Tags: support, tags

I was wondering why there were zeros next to each tag even though they had been used multiple times.

Comment: Are you talking about the tags in your profile?

Comment: [meta-tag:Status-norepro]. I see [lots of different numbers.](http://imgur.com/AKTaZX5) Could you provide a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: I' talking about the unexplained 0s in front of the tags

Answer (score 3):

The 0 next to the tag in your profile means you have 0 score on the tag. The score comes from all your posts scores' in the tag combined. I'll explain this using a screenshot from my profile:

[image: 69 Tags - 141 terraria x 22]

Here you can see "141 [terraria](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria) x 22". This means I have 22 answers and questions with [terraria](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria) tag, and the answers have 141 score in total.

Comment: thank you for the answers

Comment: @3ventic - isn't it just answer score? Hence why OP is seeing zeros: he hasn't answered any questions in those tags (or at least hasn't garnered any upvotes)

Comment: @Robotnik You are correct, edited.